# jquery Slide Toggle doesn't work with each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I have a problem here [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5Tygp/658/). I don't know why it doesn't work.
Let's look the following code to understand it better.

HTML

```
<div class="click">List 1</div>
<div class="information">Info 1</div>

<div class="click">List 2</div>
<div class="information">Info 2</div>
```

CSS

```
.information {
    display:none; 
}
```

JS

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.information').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

I tried one by one it doesn't work at all. Can you help me fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does exactly what it should - it runs `slideToggle` on all `.information` tags.

If you just want the one right after the clicked item, you can do:

```
$(this).next('.information').slideToggle('slow');
```

Comment: I would still suggest to nest your Code like showed [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asustaba/5Tygp/660/) to maintain Code readability.

Comment: +1 to both dave and Noah, for (1) having exactly the answer I would have given, and (2) giving exactly the suggestion I had in mind ..you should mark this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Your selector inside the click callback must be specific to the element that was clicked.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.information').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5Tygp/661/)